# Generate all possibilities for a string where some letters can be numbers, in Python

Tags: python, combinations

Say I have a string like this.

```
sentence = "i like to go fishing on saturday"
```

And some letters can be numbers, in the tradition of '1337' speak i.e. h3110, h0w 4r3 y0u?

However I want to get all possible combinations where some letters are converted to numbers, but others are not. Some examples with the above sentence.

```
"i 1ik3 70 g0 fishing 0n s4turd4y"
"i lik3 70 g0 fishing 0n s4turd4y"
"i like 70 g0 fishing 0n s4turd4y"
"i 1ike 70 g0 fishing 0n s4turd4y"
etc.
```

How could I write in Python a dictionary of substitutions for each letter and then a way to generate all possible combinations for the sentence?

Comment: I have a feeling you're going to be blown away by the amount of combinations that exist for this kind of problem. Most people are...

Comment: Where is your python dictionary showing the letter to number substitutions? At least show this, and maybe we can help you with the second part.

Comment: @ alfasin I hope you enjoy my sarcastic comment as much as I did your patronising remark!

@ Shadow With the actual phrase I wanted to use this on and the substitutions I'm allowing, it was 1280 combinations.

@RoadRunner I didn't want to provide how I would implement the substitutions because it might artificially restrict someone's answer. For example, the way it was done in the accepted answer by Paul Panzer I never would've thought to do myself. However, my way would've been something like this { 'a': ['4'], 'i': ['!', '1'], 'l': ['1'] }. Paul's is much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the dictionary from pairs and then use `itertools.product` for  all combinations:

```
import itertools

# 1: write down pairs
pairs = ['a4', 't7', 'e3'] # etc.
# 2: make dict; it will be convenient to store both letter and substitute as value
pd = {p[0]:p for p in pairs}
# 3: replace all eligible letters with the appropriate pair and
#    use itertools.product
[''.join(c) for c in itertools.product(*(pd.get(i, i) for i in 'i like to go fishing on saturday'))]
# ['i like to go fishing on saturday', 'i like to go fishing on saturd4y', 
#  'i like to go fishing on sa7urday', 'i like to go fishing on sa7urd4y',
#  'i like to go fishing on s4turday', 'i like to go fishing on s4turd4y',
#  'i like to go fishing on s47urday', 'i like to go fishing on s47urd4y',
#  'i like 7o go fishing on saturday', 'i like 7o go fishing on saturd4y',
#  'i like 7o go fishing on sa7urday', 'i like 7o go fishing on
#  ...
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Didn't know about the product function in itertools.

Answer (score 1):

Write a list of substitutions, such as

```
[
  [1, 'l'],
  [3, 'e'],
  [4, 'a'],
  ...
]
```

Next, divide your text into sections, separating any letter that you can substitute.  For instance, "fishing on saturday" becomes

```
[ "fishing ", "o", "n s", "a", "turd", "a", "y"]
```

Now, bring in the substitution lists for all appropriate letters: `o a a` in this case.  Use `itertools.product` to generate all of the possible combinations.

Is that enough to get you started?  Implementation is left as an exercise for the student.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary manual. But get all combinations with `itertools.combinations`

```
from itertools import combinations

sentence = "i like to go fishing on saturday"

d = {'l' : '1',
     'e' : '3',
     't' : '7'}

for l in range(len(d)):
    for x in combinations(d, l):
        for k in x:
            s = sentence.replace(k, d[k])
            print(s)
```

But this version will replace all `t` to `7`. Not match all your requirement.